# サービス層で宣言的トランザクションを扱いたい

Tags: java-ee, jpa

```
// DAO
@Transactional
public class UserDAO implements UserDAOInterface {

    @Inject
    EntityManager em;

    public User find(int id) {
        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        em.merge(user);
        em.flush();
    }

    // こちらは正常にトランザクション処理が実行（ロールバック）される
    public void transaction(User buyer, Item item) {
        User seller = find(item.getSellerId());
        int price = item.getPrice();
        buyer.setBalance(buyer.getBalance() - price);
        update(buyer);
        if(true) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        seller.setBalance(seller.getBalance() + price);
        update(seller);
    }

}
```

上記のDAOのtransactionメソッドを呼び出した場合は正常にロールバックされるのですが，

```
// サービス層（ビジネスロジック）
@Transactional
public class UserLogic implements UserLogicInterface{

    UserDAOInterface dao = Guice.createInjector(new JpaPersistDaoModule())
            .getInstance(UserDAO.class);

    public User signIn(String email, String password) {
        return dao.find(email, password);
    }

    // こちらは正常に実行（ロールバック）されない
    public void transaction(User buyer, Item item) {
        User seller = dao.find(item.getSellerId());
        int price = item.getPrice();
        buyer.setBalance(buyer.getBalance() - price);
        dao.update(buyer);
        if(true) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        seller.setBalance(seller.getBalance() + price);
        dao.update(seller);
    }

}
```

こちら側のメソッドを呼び出した場合ではうまくいきませんでした（メソッドはコピー＆ペースト）．

実現したいのは後者のほうです（でないと，ビジネスロジックにEntityManagerを持たせかつそれをDAOのメソッドに引数として渡すという気持ちの悪いことをしなければなりません）．よろしくお願いします．

補足です．
Google Guice と PostgresSQL を使用しています．

Comment: `UserLogic`の生成(インジェクション)はどのようになっていますか?

Comment: すみません、自己解決したので、後ほど詳細を投稿致します。ご指摘の通り、userlogicのインジェクションが原因でした。

Answer (score 0):

問題があったのは以下のコードでした．

```
// サービス層（ビジネスロジック）
@Transactional
public class UserLogic implements UserLogicInterface{

    UserDAOInterface dao = Guice.createInjector(new JpaPersistDaoModule())
            .getInstance(UserDAO.class);

    public User signIn(String email, String password) {
        return dao.find(email, password);
    }

    // こちらは正常に実行（ロールバック）されない
    public void transaction(User buyer, Item item) {
        User seller = dao.find(item.getSellerId());
        int price = item.getPrice();
        buyer.setBalance(buyer.getBalance() - price);
        dao.update(buyer);
        if(true) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        seller.setBalance(seller.getBalance() + price);
        dao.update(seller);
    }

}
```

このコードの

```
UserDAOInterface dao = Guice.createInjector(new JpaPersistDaoModule())
            .getInstance(UserDAO.class);
```

この部分です．ここを

```
@Inject
UserDAOInterface dao;
```

と書き換えます．
さらに，このクラスを生成するときに
`new UserLogic();`
とするのではなく，
`UserLogic logic = Guice.createInjector(new JpaPersistDaoModule()).getInstance(UserLogic.class);`
とするのが正解だったみたいです．

お騒がせいたしました．